# Activar proveedor de autenticación en FirebaseLoginViewController

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode, firebase

Estoy intentando usar `FirebaseLoginViewController` para poder autenticar a mis usuarios. De momento el código lo tengo así:

```
import UIKit

class AccesoPrincipal : FirebaseLoginViewController{


var loginViewController : FirebaseLoginViewController?
var loginButton : FirebaseLoginButton?
var logoutButton : FirebaseLoginButton?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let firebaseRef = Firebase(url: "https://superapp.firebaseio.com/")

    self.loginViewController = FirebaseLoginViewController(ref: firebaseRef)
    self.loginViewController!.enableProvider(FAuthProvider.Facebook)
    //self.loginViewController.enableProvider(FAuthProvider.Google)
    //self.loginViewController.enableProvider(FAuthProvider.Twitter)
    self.loginViewController!.enableProvider(FAuthProvider.Password)


    // Scenario 2: Set up user action based login flow
    loginButton!.addTarget(self, action: "login", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    logoutButton!.addTarget(self, action: "logout", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
}


// Scenario 2: User action launches login flow, dismissal and routing handled by `FirebaseLoginViewController`
func login() {
    if ((self.loginViewController!.currentUser() == nil)) {
        self.presentViewController(self.loginViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

override func logout() {
    if ((self.loginViewController!.currentUser()) != nil) {
        self.loginViewController!.logout()
        }
    }
}
```

Al momento de ejecutar la aplicación me aparece el siguiente código de error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Please enable at least one authentication provider in your FirebaseLoginViewController'

```
2016-02-16 19:39:57.725 MyApp[3623:91775] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Please enable at least one authentication provider in your FirebaseLoginViewController'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01138a14 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0429ee02 objc_exception_throw + 50
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0113893d +[NSException raise:format:] + 141
    3   MyApp                    0x001b18f4 -[FirebaseLoginViewController viewDidLoad] + 292
    4   MyApp                    0x0005b7a5 _TFC16MyApp15AccesoPrincipal11viewDidLoadfS0_FT_T_ + 85
    5   MyApp                    0x0005bd32 _TToFC16MyApp15AccesoPrincipal11viewDidLoadfS0_FT_T_ + 34
    6   UIKit                               0x01fdd2ae -[UIViewController _sendViewDidLoadWithAppearanceProxyObjectTaggingEnabled] + 44
    7   UIKit                               0x01fe1dce -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1384
    8   UIKit                               0x01fe21ed -[UIViewController view] + 35
    9   UIKit                               0x01e8ff94 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 69
    10  UIKit                               0x01e906b1 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 304
    11  UIKit                               0x01e90a67 -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
    12  UIKit                               0x01ea4118 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 80
    13  UIKit                               0x01e0c6e7 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4190
    14  UIKit                               0x01e13cd6 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1989
    15  UIKit                               0x01e38ee5 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke3218 + 68
    16  UIKit                               0x01e10966 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 163
    17  FrontBoardServices                  0x06377c76 __37-[FBSWorkspace clientEndTransaction:]_block_invoke_2 + 71
    18  FrontBoardServices                  0x0637774d __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 54
    19  FrontBoardServices                  0x06395173 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 184
    20  FrontBoardServices                  0x063955aa -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 52
    21  FrontBoardServices                  0x063948a6 FBSSerialQueueRunLoopSourceHandler + 33
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x010526ff __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0104838b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 523
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x010477a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x010470e6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x01046efb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    27  UIKit                               0x01e10206 -[UIApplication _run] + 540
    28  UIKit                               0x01e15bfa UIApplicationMain + 160
    29  MyApp                    0x00060f0c main + 140
    30  libdyld.dylib                       0x04d0ba21 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Entiendo que el error es por que no se detecta que se haya activado algún proveedor de autenticación, sin embargo esa parte si esta definida dentro del `viewController`, no es así?. No hay mucha documentación de `FirebaseUI` por lo que ha sido difícil encontrar algo al respecto.

Comment: Recuerda que también hay que activarlo en el dashboard de tu app:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/user-auth.html#section-enable-providers

Comment: Hola mhergon en efecto en el dashboard tengo activada autenticacion por facebook y por email&password. tengo tambien creada  y configurada la app en facebook. No veo otro camino a seguir

Comment: ¿Hay la posibilidad de que subas el código a Dropbox o similar para verlo en directo?

Comment: Por supuesto @mhergon. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4915071/MyApp.zip Se esta subiendo calculo que en 15 minutos ya debe estar completo. Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Después de revisar el código, te cuento el error. El problema principal es que has declarado `AccesoPrincipal` como una subclase de `FirebaseLoginViewController` y se instanciaba directamente sin los parámetros necesarios. Para solventarlo, he modificado el código para que quede tal que así:

```
import UIKit

class AccesoPrincipal : UIViewController {

    var loginViewController : FirebaseLoginViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let firebaseRef = Firebase(url: "https://puertomapp.firebaseio.com/")

        self.loginViewController = FirebaseLoginViewController(ref: firebaseRef)
        self.loginViewController!.enableProvider(FAuthProvider.Facebook)
        self.loginViewController!.enableProvider(FAuthProvider.Password)

    }


    @IBAction func login() {
        if ((self.loginViewController!.currentUser() == nil)) {
            self.presentViewController(self.loginViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

}
```

Te dejo también el código modificado, ya que he añadido el botón que abre la pantalla de login. Aquí está: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jamv2eo40ixjf2k/PuertoMorelosApp_Modificada.zip?dl=0

Comment: Funciona!!!. En realidad te agradezco mucho **@mhergon** me has aclarado muchas cosas con el código corregido.

Comment: De nada Victor!